# "It's a-me !" -- just an imitation of an Italian accent or something more?

Tags: phrases, slang, accent

I've seen and heard this at various times:

> It's a-me! [first name]!

(Most of the time, seemingly as a reference to [Mario](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mario).) I was wondering what the intent was behind the construction "a-me".

Is it just to transcribe an Italian accent? In that case, what is it about it that sounds Italian to a native English speaker?

Or maybe is it conveying something more, like perhaps a lack of education?

Comment: Actually, transcribing an Italian accent, I would probably write **It's-a me**.  Done that way because our mythical Italian is not used to words ending in consonants.

Comment: Thanks, that explanation is really what I was looking for! If you give it as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The phonotactics of Italian does not include a sequence -*tsm*-, therefore Italian speakers *naturally* pronounce it dropping a vowel between -*ts*- (rendered as [ʦ] as in "razza", 'race' /ˈraʦʦa/ or, in phonemic notation, [ˈratːsˑa]) and -*m*-. The standard epenthetic vowel in Italy is [e]: e.g. in Tuscan, "sport" is, again, *naturally* pronounced [ˈspɔrte].

[**Epenthesis**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epenthesis) is a widespread phonetic phenomenon in substandard speech across Italy.

Comment: +1, though I have to point out that _razza_ is not pronounced [ˈraʦʦa] (that would have a non-allowed sequence of two fricatives after each other and would, by epenthesis, become [ˈraʦeʦa]), but rather [ˈraʦːa]. :-)

Comment: That is definitely true. In fact, my transcription was not accurate, since I included it in square brackets (phonetic notation); so yours is the right one. However, if we were to transcript it in phonological terms, it would be correct to note it as /ˈraʦʦa/. I'll correct my answer. :-) If any of you can read Italian, I suggest you take a look at [this post](http://www.achyra.org/cruscate/viewtopic.php?p=27610#27610).

Answer (score 12):

from comment to answer ...

Actually, transcribing an Italian accent, I would probably write **It's-a me**. Done that way because our mythical Italian is not used to words ending in consonants.

Comment: If I as an Italian had to transcribe it, it would rather be "It's-e me". But that's because our 'e' is pronounced [ɛ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-mid_front_unrounded_vowel "'e' as in 'open'"), and that's the sound we apparently accidentally put at the end of English words.

Answer (score 6):

It's always attributed to Mario because he would say that in [Super Mario 64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Mario_64) [(audio)](http://youtu.be/ZhadLMDWcGA)... When you started up the game, he would say "It's a-me, Mario"... There are likely other places that used this, but this is the reason it's attributed to Mario.

Admittedly, I have heard it used as a terrible Italian accent, but [Gen Y](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generation_Y) grew up hearing it on video games :)

Comment: ...the younger half of Gen X as well.

Comment: Please note that as @GEdgar says in the comment, it's "It's-a me, Mario" not "It's a-me, Mario".